# Directives Talking to Controllers - Why isn't my module working? (Angular JS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm currently learning Angular using this video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LJmZaxuxlRc&feature=share&list=PLP6DbQBkn9ymGQh2qpk9ImLHdSH5T7yw7

The goal of this tutorial is to roll over an element and have an alert box pop up... but when the console is throwing an error when I start the app:

> Uncaught Error: No module: twitterApp

I've copied the code word for word so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Check out a demo and the code below:

http://plnkr.co/edit/tLsD394P0WmeQqLBm8F8?p=preview

```
<div ng-app="twitterApp">
    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">

      <div enter="loadMoreTweets()">Roll over to load more tweets</div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

```
var app = angular.module('twitterApp', [])

app.controller("AppCtrl", function ($scope) {
      $scope.loadMoreTweets = function () {
        alert("Loading tweets!");
      }
  })

app.directive("enter", function () {
  return function (scope, element, attrs) {
    element.bind("mouseenter", function () {
        scope.$apply("loadMoreTweets()")
    })
  }
})
```

EDIT: Didn't work on Google Chrome locally but it did work on Safari

Comment: Your code is working fine for me. No errors whatsoever.

Comment: Just tried it on Safari.. worked as expected

Comment: I'm using Chrome v29 on Ubuntu and it works as expected.

Comment: I'm on Chrome 27 w/ a Mac... I've had problems running angular locally on chrome in the past too. Safari is ok but I like the dev tools on Chrome better.

Answer (score 0):

Source of egghead.io angularjs lessons are available on github take a look https://github.com/msfrisbie/egghead-angularjs

Hope it helps.!!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I agree with your point. I just wanted to add that as a comment but did not see a way to do it so added as an answer. My intention was to let everyone know that the source of videos in egghead.io is available at github so that anyone who is unable to get it working correctly can take reference.

Comment: Once you have earned sufficien reputations you will be able to post comments.